# Use a custom name for a request parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

After changing job I'm learning C# and Entity Framework; previously I worked with Java + Spring.

The question is: Is there an equivalent way to write this Java code into C# code?

```java
public ModelAndView showUser(@RequestParam("k") String userName)
```

With Spring and the annotation `RequestParam` I could convert a request parameter named `k` into a more friendly and readable parameter named `userName`; so now, I expect a C# code like this:

```cs
public ActionResult showUser([RequestParam("k")] string userName)
```

Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do the same as in Java+spring but in C# MVC you can use Modal to transfer data from and to.
There you don't have to get the each and every request value separately you just have to mention your Modal Name in the parameter parentheses.

Answering your question, if tried to assign the value from the parameter it will throw

> Default parameter for name must be a compile-time constant

```
public ActionResult Contact(string name = Request.Form["param1"])
{
    return View();
}
```

Above code throws an error.
So to work with that used

```
 public ActionResult Contact()
 {
    string name = Request.Form["param1"];
    return View();
 }
```

This will work.
I recommend you to use Modal and data annotations concept for the passing of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult showUser([FromQuery(Name = "k")] string userName)
{...}
```